# magento add options not readable for customer

Tags: magento

Simple question, but i can't find the answer on the world wide web.

Is there a way to add some data to a product in Magento that is nog readable for the costumer on the website. I want to add some data like productnumber supplier and price of purchasing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I'm a little surprised that you haven't found the answer to this. This is just basic product attributes. Do a search for Magento Product Attributes.